# Cross validation in R with SVM

Tags: r, svm, cross-validation

I am new to R.
I am trying to use a SVM algorithm to use in a regression data set.
I have this:

```
d1 <- read.table("forestfires.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)

train<-d1[1:465,]
test <-d1[466:517,]

library(e1071)

sapply(train,summary)  

library(caret)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", savePred=T)
mod <- train(area~., data=d1, method = "svmLinear", trControl = ctrl)

summary(mod)

predict(mod, test)
```

This happens with no errors. But I want to cross validate the algorithm. I tried this:

```
library(crossval)

CVSVMModel = crossval(fit2)
cverror_individual = kfoldLoss(CVSVMmodel,'Mode','individual')
```

But I got this error:

```
Error in group.samples(Y) : argument "Y" is missing, with no default`enter code here`
```

Does someone know what can I do?

Comment: My suspicion is that for either `crossval` or `kfoldLoss`, there is a missing argument named Y. Look in the help docs and figure out if this is true and what values it wants. ALternatively, there may be some argument similar to group.samples in one of these functions.

Comment: `caret::train` already performed 10-fold cross validation (default is 10 if `method = "cv"` and `number` not specified).